# How to quickly sort dict() with a huge number of keys?

Tags: python, sorting

TLE always happen in SBANK [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.pl) using python. In order to solve it, i have to sort `dict()`, though `dict()` has huge number of `KEYS`(maximum--100000). Use `sorted()` function in my code takes no effect. Is there any fast solution? Thanks for your help.

My code below:

```
for j in range(n): # n is the number of keys
        account = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
        dic.setdefault(account, 0)
        dic[account] += 1
sorted(dic) # **this sort take a lot of time**
```

---

**EDIT1**:According to Justin Peel's tips, i update my code below, but return still TLE. How can i do?

```
import sys
import psyco # import psyco module to speed up
psyco.full()
nCase = int(sys.stdin.readline().split()[0])
for i in range(nCase):
    n = int(sys.stdin.readline().split()[0])
    dic = dict()
    lst = list()
    for j in range(n):
        account = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
        dic.setdefault(account, 0)
        dic[account] += 1
    sys.stdin.readline()
    lst = dic.keys() # store keys in list
    lst.sort()
    for account in lst:
        sys.stdout.write('%s %s\n' % (account, dic[account]))
```

Comment: There's no need for `lst = list()`. Also, using `setdefault` will slow you down a lot. It is faster to check explicitly if `account` is in `dic`, add 1 if true and set to 1 if not true. Also, using `readline()` over and over again isn't a great way of doing this. You can `read()` the whole file and use some variable as an index that you move around manually, or, because the account lines are all the same length, you can read in all of the lines that you need at once using `read(correct_number_of_chars)` and then split them on the new line. `rstrip()` is slowing you down too.

Comment: @Justin Peel Hey, i have got AC, thanks for your tips. BTW, it is my fault that not wrap process into a function using psyco module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem. Here are some tips:

1. Use Python 2.5. It is much faster than Python 3.2 which is the other option available on SPOJ with Python. Only one person has been able to get a fast enough solution using Python 3.2
2. Just use a basic dict for counting. You can get by with the defaultdict from the collections module too, but the basic dict was faster for me.
3. Sort only the keys of the dict, not the key-item pairs. Forming the key-item pairs takes far too long. Also, use `keys = mydict.keys(); keys.sort()` because it is the fastest way to go about it.
4. Use psyco (pretty much always with SPOJ problems in Python)
5. Learn the fastest ways to do input and output in Python. Hint: it isn't iterating over every line of input for example.
6. Try submitting after you've added each part (getting input, counting, doing output) to see where you are with time. This is a very valuable thing to do on SPOJ. The SPOJ computer running your code is quite likely much slower than your current computer and it can be hard to determine based on your own computer's running time of the code if it will be fast enough for SPOJ.

Answer (score 2):

`dict`s are not sorted, which is how they are able to provide O(1) insert and get access. (Internally, they are implemented as hash tables, I believe, though I'm not sure this is required by the Python spec).

If you want to iterate the keys of a `dict` in sorted order, you can use:

```
for key in sorted(the_dict.iterkeys()):
    value = the_dict[key]
    # do something
```

But, as you note, sorting 100,000 elements may take some time.

As an alternative, you can write (or find on the internet) sorted `dict` implementations that keep an ordered list of keys along with the dictionary, and support fast lookup by key, and iteration in order without having to sort all at once. Of course, to support sorted order, the keys will need to be sorted at insertion time, so inserts will not be O(1).

**Edit:** Per [dsolimano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58074/dsolimano)'s comment, if you are using Python 2.7 or Python 3.x, there is a built-in `OrderedDict` class that orders iteration in insertion order. This keeps insertion fast, but may not do what you need (depending on the order of items you want).

Comment: In fact, Python now has a built-in ordered dictionary - http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: D'oh! I was searching for `SortedDict`, not `OrderedDict`.

Comment: I think I had used a third-party class named `SortedDict` at some point... never worked with C#

Comment: Just as a note here on speed - calling sorted on an iterator isn't generally a good way to go when speed is important. `x = the_dict.keys(); x.sort()` is faster than both `sorted(thedict.iterkeys())` and `sorted(thedict.keys())` (the second of which is faster). It does actually make a difference with SPOJ. The fastest way is more than 25% faster than the slowest way.

Comment: I seriously doubt that using the OrderedDict class will be fast enough in Python 3.2 for SPOJ because it is written in Python. It is a great thing to use in practice, but, for a problem with very time-sensitive parameters like most of the ones on SPOJ, it won't be fast enough.

Comment: @Justin good to know, re: making a list and then `.sort()`ing it... makes sense, now that I think about it in the light of day.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.1 is available, [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is good for that purpose:

```
collections.Counter(map(str.rstrip, sys.stdin)).most_common()
```